# Как добавить элемент в многомерный массив?

Tags: массивы, javascript

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr[1][1] = 2;
alert(a[1][1]);
```

Почему undefined и как правильно добавить элемент в многомерный массив?

Comment: @websav,

1. Вы задаете одномерный массив, а потом пытаетесь работать с ним, как с многомерным. Если уж преобразовывать, то по-человечески:

        arr[1] = [];
        arr[1][1] = 2;

2. Задаете вы `arr`, а алертуете `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
//Или так:
arr[1] = [];
arr[1].push(2);//arr[1][0] = 2;
//Или так:
arr[1] = {1:2};//arr[1][1] = 2;
```

Comment: Второй вариант чудесен, спасибо.

Comment: Отлично. Соррь: `arr[1] = [];` пропустил в первом варианте.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

alert(arr[1]); // 2
```